# cypher zero length path default matching rule

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Do these cypher notations `(a)-[*]->(b)` and `(a)-[*..5]->(b)` include this pattern `(a)-[*0]->(b)` by default (meaning a and b are the same node)?
**or**
Do I need to explicitly spell it out like `(a)-[*0..]->(b)` and `(a)-[*0..5]->(b)` ?

This is especially handy for optional matching of edges / subpaths.
See reference documentation on [MATCH](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-match.html) and [Patterns](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/introduction-pattern.html) in case I missed it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the docs:

> Nodes that are a variable number of relationship→node hops away can be found using the following syntax: -[:TYPE*minHops..maxHops]->. minHops and maxHops are optional and default to 1 and infinity respectively. When no bounds are given the dots may be omitted.

So to match a path with length 0 you have to explicitly use 0 as minHops:

```
(a)-[*0..5]->(b)
```

This will match a path from 0 to 5 hops, so `a` and `b` might refer to the same node.

In contrast `(a)-[*..5]-(b)` will match from 1 to 5 hops.